# How to integrate this integral?

Tags: calculus, integration

I had a problem with this specific integral:
$$
\int{\sqrt{\frac{x^3 -3}{x^{11}}} \ dx}
$$

Thank you ahead of time.

Comment: W|A says answer is $\frac{2}{27}x^{12}\left(\frac{x^3-3}{x^{11}}\right)^{\large\frac{3}{2}}$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sub $x=1/u$, $dx=-du/u^2$ to get

$$-\int \frac{du}{u^2} u^{11/2} \sqrt{\frac{1}{u^3}-3} = -\int du \, u^2 \sqrt{1-3 u^3}$$

Next sub $v=u^3$ and you should be able to take it from there.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

$$\int{\sqrt{\frac{x^3 -3}{x^{11}}} \ dx}$$

Take $x^3$ common from the numerator:
$$\int{\sqrt{\frac{x^3 (1 -3x^{-3})}{x^{11}}} \ dx}$$

The integral then becomes
$$\int{x^{-4}\sqrt{(1 -3x^{-3})} \ dx}$$

Now, set $x^{-3}=t$.

Thus,
$$ x^{-4} dx = -\frac{1}{3}dt $$

You can now handle this.

Answer (score 1):

$$ \int \sqrt{\frac{x^3-3}{x^{11}}}\,dx = \int \frac{1}{x^4} \sqrt{\frac{x^3-3}{x^3}} \,dx 
= \int \frac{1}{x^4} \sqrt{1-\frac{3}{x^3}} \,dx $$

Let 
$$ u = \frac{1}{x^3}, \; du = -\frac{3}{x^4} dx $$

The above integral becomes

$$ -\frac{1}{3} \int \sqrt{1-3u}\:du = -\frac{1}{3} \cdot -\frac{1}{3} \cdot \frac{2}{3} 
(1-3u)^{3/2} + C = \frac{2}{27} \left(1 - \frac{3}{x^3}\right)^{3/2} + C $$